# Cycle not working with pgfplots \foreach

Tags: pgfplots, foreach

I'm trying to plot some data from a text file, and I would like to be able to cycle the styles of the markers using a custom list. I was able to get the cycle list working, but when I added error bars, problems arose. Originally, my code was as follows:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}

\pgfplotscreateplotcyclelist{mylist}{%
{black,mark=square,draw=none},
{black,mark=o,draw=none},
{black,mark=triangle,draw=none},
{black,mark=diamond,draw=none}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        legend pos=south east,
        legend entries={Trial 1,
                        Trial 2,
                        Trial 3},
        cycle list name=mylist,
        legend image post style = only marks
        ]

        \foreach \yindex in {2,4,6}
        \addplot  table[x index = 0, y index = \yindex] {data.txt};
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This produced the following image:

[image: Picture of my working plot without error bars]

I then made the following change to be able to add the error columns to my plot, which resulted in a plot that didn't contain any of my marker information, but rather made straight lines between points with no markers.

[image: Picture of my plot with improper formatting]

```
\foreach[evaluate=\yindex as \ynext using int(\yindex+1)] \yindex in {2,4,6}
    \addplot [error bars/.cd,y dir=both,y explicit, x dir = both, x explicit] 
        table[x index = 0, x error index = 1, y index = \yindex, y error index = \ynext]
        {data.txt};
```

Any ideas that might have caused this problem and/or how to remedy it? I'd really appreciate it, thanks!

EDIT: Forgot to include the data file being loaded. If it is of interest, it is a simple tab delimited file. Alternating columns (1,3,5,7) correspond to plot values, and (2,4,6,8) correspond to the error bars associated. Columns 1 and 2 are the x axis.

```
23    0.25    1.75    0.0625    1.625    0.0625    1.75     0.0625
25    0.25    1.75    0.0625    1.75     0.0625    1.875    0.0625
27    0.25    2.125   0.0625    2        0.0625    2.25     0.0625
29    0.25    2.5     0.0625    2.5      0.0625    2.5      0.0625
31    0.25    2.5     0.0625    2.5      0.0625    2.5      0.0625
33    0.25    2.5     0.0625    2.5      0.0625    2.5      0.0625
```

Comment: We'd like to keep answers separate from questions, so you should write a separate answer instead of editing your answer into the question. Self-answers are perfectly admissible, and a well-written answer may earn you additional reputation.

Comment: Also, a tip: you can use backticks `\`` to [mark inline code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863). So "\addplot" can be `\addplot`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to fix this by changing the `\addplot` command to `\addplot+` and by adding the `cycle list name` parameter in the `\addplot+` command. Hope this helps someone else!

Here's the final code in my particular issue:

```
\foreach[evaluate=\yindex as \ynext using int(\yindex+1)] \yindex in {2,4,6}
    \addplot+ [cycle list name=mylist,error bars/.cd,y dir=both,y explicit,x dir = both, x
        explicit] table[x index = 0, x error index = 1, y index = \yindex, y error index = 
        \ynext] {data.txt};
```

Comment: Please consider accepting your answer, so that your question be removed from the "unanswered" pile.

Comment: I had a similar problem and was able to solve it, using only `\addplot*` (only defining `cycle list` once in the `axis` environment).